# I accidentally sent bitcoins twice to the same address

Tags: transactions, bitcoin-core, address-reuse

Accidentally, I have transfered BTC from my one wallet to another twice on the same address. First transaction was successful, but in the second case the BTC got deducted from one of my wallet but not credited into my other wallet.

Help how to get my bitcoins back?

Comment: Is it showing as a unconfirmed transaction in your second wallet?Add your transaction IDs to the question to get a better idea of what is going on.

Comment: 25f46bfe9c72b80809ec1cb49248ae15a7a29533bb4788b316890fab267f5d44
1Q9YcURWiM6E25xZJz8LJWseEmhcLiFKo2 ($ 1,013.57 - Output)
1K7cd3Y76Vh5XeMSSaHsF9D5bip1oDX1wG ($ 343.22 - Output)
 1HooJvDbS1rrenxn61tjjfuGPr7RSeJrTa - (Unspent) $ 154.03
3BJJGZAop4h3TKBx4B1XmrH2R9ChJuSFBP - (Spent) $ 1,200.06
$ 1,354.09
Summary
Size 371 (bytes)
Received Time  2017-05-27 06:47:46
Included In Blocks 468337 ( 2017-05-27 07:12:48 + 25 minutes ) 
Confirmations 859 Confirmations

Comment: This is only 1 transaction and is confirmed. Can also share the second one?

Answer (score 4):

It is not clear what exactly happened.

1. If you've made two subsequent transactions to the same address that should not be a problem. Addresses can be used more than once to receive money.
2. If you created two transactions that spend the same transaction outputs, there is no problem, because only one of them can confirm.
3. If your transaction simply didn't get confirmed yet, there is little to no problem: Transactions either have confirmed or have not. Since both wallets are your own, the money is still in your sending wallet until it is in your receiving wallet. If you wish to get help about fixing a stuck unconfirmed transaction please refer to: [Why is my transaction not getting confirmed and what can I do about it?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/9046/5046)

If your question is not covered by these three scenarios, please edit your post to clarify what you're asking.